# Data Encryption with Linked Servers In SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server, encryption, linked-server

````
    We have MS Access Databases and they are linked to SQL servers via linked servers. 
    
    We would like to enable the data encryption when data transit between SQL server and linked servers. 
    
    In this process, We added Encrypt=Yes option in linked server definition while creating.
 ```   
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
    @server = N'REGISTRATION_NAME',
    @srvproduct=N'',
    @provider=N'SQLNCLI',
    @datasrc=N'SERVER\INSTANCE',
    @provstr=N'Encrypt=yes;',
    @catalog = 'DATABASE_NAME'
   ``` 
    After this, We get different errors when I try to query from linked servers.
    Here are the some of the errors.
````

*SSMS throws error
"Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server"*

- If the security option is "Not be made" then below error is throwing.
  "Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider) *

  Please help me to understand and resolve these errors.

Comment: Does the target SQL Server instance have a CA-signed certificate installed on it? (Unlikely, by the way.) SQL Server certificates are self-signed by default so when using `Encrypt=yes;` you usually need to accompany it with `TrustServerCertificate=yes;` as well.

Comment: SQL Server has the CA-Signed certificate installed. So how can we keep this TrustServerCertificate=yes; in linked server definition?

Comment: /****** Object:  LinkedServer [Databasename]    Script Date: 5/3/2022 11:46:05 AM ******/
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'Databasename', @srvproduct=N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', @provider=N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', @datasrc=N'c:\test.mdb', @provstr=N'Encrypted=yes;TrustServerCertificate=True'